# What secure encryption algorithm can I use with Windows L2TP client?

Tags: vpn, mikrotik, l2tp

I successfully got a Mikrotik router to run as L2TP server, but it looks like Windows clients would fail to connect if I remove 3DES, which is not exactly secure, from the list of encryption algorithm. I have the choices of: 3DES, AES-256, AES-192, AES-128, Blowfish, Twofish, Camellia-256, Camellia-192 and Camellia-128.

Answer (score -1):

L2TP doesn't provide any encryption.You can choose to use 256-bit AES encryption. Using a 256-bit AES key could potentially offer more security against future attempts to access your files.

For example, if it would take a quadrillion years to brute-force 128-bit AES, does it really matter that it might take even longer to brute-force 256-bit AES? For all realistic purposes, they’re equally secure.

Comment: I tried just that and it did not work. The log would say: no suitable proposal found.

Comment: Than check 3rd party tool blowfish, you have to download the serup